# Globally enable ONLY "/tp" command without plugins/mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is this possible? We upgraded to 1.9 now and I'm searching for a solution that does not require plugins (like PermissionEX, or similar).

I know that there are some nice `/gamerules`, but they don't cover this issue as far as I know.
OP-Permission-level 2 is way to mighty and not an option for me to activate. We play survival and we only want this command available, if possible.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Hmm... You could use command blocks to test if someone has done a certain command (like `/give`, you could test if they had a certain item and take it away (there are limitations to this)) and revert it, but this is hard. I think you need them plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Now as far as I know giving someone perms to use /tp without them being oped is not possible, but I rigged up a system in which you can let none oped people teleport to players. (mind you it only works to players)

Basically you have a teleport hub where the person who wants to teleport gets turned into spectator mode. `/gamemode 3` (you can teleport to people (in spectator mode) using your hotbar keys) Now all you need to do is make a system to turn them back into back into survival (or a gamemode of your choice). I would do this by making a scoreboard adding all people who are in spectator and when the score of the person reaches the number you want you turn them back into survival.

The chain of commandblocks would look something like this

```
/scoreboard players add @a[m=3] spectatorMode 1

/gamemode 0 @a[score_spectatorMode_min=200]
```

This would turn anyone in spectatorMode into survival after 10 seconds. Also note you would have to run this command to get the scoreboard.

```
/scoreboard objectives spectatorMode dummy
```

Also remember to put the chain of commandblocks in the spawn chunks so they will always work. Hope this helped!